# Another Iterating and printing JSON objects in Python

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

Here is the JSON:

> ```
> "behavior": {
>     "processes": [
>         {
>             "parent_id": 1396, 
>             "process_name": "virussign.com_0fb139b14aff7c13c22a609c14926740.vir", 
>             "process_id": 1540, 
>             "first_seen": "2014-05-15 17:12:41,749", 
>             "calls": [
>                 {
>                     "category": "system", 
>                     "status": true, 
>                     "return": "0x00000000", 
>                     "timestamp": "2014-05-15 17:12:41,849", 
>                     "thread_id": "1544", 
>                     "repeated": 0, 
>                     "api": "LdrGetProcedureAddress", 
>                     "arguments": [
>                         {
>                             "name": "Ordinal", 
>                             "value": "0"
>                         }, 
>                         {
>                             "name": "FunctionName", 
>                             "value": "LoadLibraryA"
>                         }, 
>                         {
>                             "name": "FunctionAddress", 
>                             "value": "0x7c801d7b"
>                         }, 
>                         {
>                             "name": "ModuleHandle", 
>                             "value": "0x7c800000"
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 }, 
>                 {
>                     "category": "system", 
>                     "status": true, 
>                     "return": "0x00000000", 
>                     "timestamp": "2014-05-15 17:12:41,849", 
>                     "thread_id": "1544", 
>                     "repeated": 0, 
>                     "api": "LdrGetProcedureAddress", 
>                     "arguments": [
>                         {
>                             "name": "Ordinal", 
>                             "value": "0"
>                         }, 
>                         {
>                             "name": "FunctionName", 
>                             "value": "CreateMutexA"
>                         }, 
>                         {
>                             "name": "FunctionAddress", 
>                             "value": "0x7c80e9cf"
>                         }, 
>                         {
>                             "name": "ModuleHandle", 
>                             "value": "0x7c800000"
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 },
> ```

Clues:

- 'processes' and 'calls' have unpredictable number of array inside them

Question: How can i get those api in this arrayception situation? Other way to process this are very welcome.

Here is my single print code:

> step1 = parsed_input['behavior']['processes'][0]['calls'][0]['api']
>   print step1

the result is LdrGetProcedureAddress

Comment: How about starting with `for process in parsed_input['behavior']['processes']:`?

Comment: I had tried but the error return i presume it doesn't give 'for' proper syntax.

`for prosess in parsed_input['behavior']['processes'][0]['calls'][0]['api']                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: You're missing a colon `:`, and also trying to iterate over the wrong thing.

Comment: It run very well, apparently the result printed out is the whole thing in 'processes' array. Plus thank you very much for the correction, and sorry my failurei n noticing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lists in lists, so you use a nested loop:

```
for proc in parsed_input['behaviour']['processes']:
    for call in proc['calls']:
        print call['api']
```

You can collect all these in a list comprehension:

```
apis = [call['api'] 
        for proc in parsed_input['behaviour']['processes']
        for call in proc['calls']]
```

Comment: the first nested loop answers the question already but i just wonder what 'apis' does here? and yes i tried to figure it out by running it, but it said `apis expected indentation block`
or probably i don't get what list comprehension is. Is it like putting extracted api in a variable?

Comment: @HaryantoWang: The list comprehension builds a list; it runs the nested loops exactly as the first example does, but instead of `print call['api']` it appends the result of `call['api']` to the resulting list. Your error implies that you needed to indent the line with the expression further.

Comment: i also found a [link] (http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to help understood list comprehension above. I got the idea of append now. But when i run that apis above, it show no result in the log. If i add for loop to print apis, it gives not-appended result. How can i see it appended?

Comment: @HaryantoWang: `print apis` perhaps? The list comprehension produces a list, containing the exact same values the other loop merely prints. I don't know what you wanted to *do* with the values, though.

Comment: ok, done. i slightly get the idea how to store them into database and count each of them now. Thanks a lot. That's the purpose of this.